# Scam PTC ad in Cointiply which claims to give double amount deposit, is there any way to get them, their mail is something like coinpayudouble gmai

Tags: fraud, coinbase-transaction

Ad is in Cointiply.
It even gives you receipt.
Claims to double your deposit.
Uses Cointiply and Coinbase maybe as a disquise for legitimate trust.
Their mail is something like coinpayudouble gmail.
Could they be found from their ip, mail or from their PTC ad order.